# Radius of an Ellipse Given Theta and Center (h,k)

Tags: conic-sections

I'm working on solving the equation for "r". This equation got way out of hand, and I'm not sure where to continue from here. The original equation is ( x-h / a )^2 + ( y-k / b )^2 = 1.

What I'm trying to do is compute the radius of an ellipse given an angle Theta, and the ellipse center (h,k). Where the radius line still starts at (0, 0).

I started by replacing x and y with r * cos(theta) and r * sin(theta) respectively. From there, I squared the numerator, and denominator as required by the equation which left me with an expanded equation that I would like to be able to solve for "r".

Here is a link to the work I've do so far:

[Work Here](https://postimg.cc/94kZGNm8)

On the left hand side of the image (separated by green line) is the solution for the same equation without the "-h" and "-k" parameters. And on the right is my attempt to solve for "r" with the "-h" and "-k" parameters.

I'm stuck at the spot on the right in trying to solve for "r" any assistance is much appreciated. I'm assuming there is some technique for simplifying the equation that I may have forgotten, but I'm not sure what to search for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ x=h+a \cos (\theta )$$ and $$y=k+b \sin (\theta )$$

$$r^2= x^2+y^2 = (h+a \cos (\theta ))^2 +(k+b \sin (\theta ))^2$$ and

$$r= $$

$$\sqrt {(h+a \cos (\theta ))^2 +(k+b \sin (\theta ))^2}$$

Comment: Thank you sir! You have greatly simplified my efforts.

Comment: Thank you for your attention